# How to make windows snap to the edge in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, window

In windows 7, when a window's edge came really near the edge of a screen, it would snap to that edge. This was pretty useful, but windows 8 doesn't seem to do that. Note that I'm *not* talking about the Aero "Snap" feature that also resizes the windows.

What happened to this and how can I enable it?

I'm using a system with 3 monitors on windows 8.1.

Update:

The snap-to-edge *just* started working out of nowhere. I did nothing I can think of - just possibly logged out and logged back in or slept the computer. Weird.

Comment: After a few months, my windows almost never snap to the sides of the screen. No idea why it sometimes works and usually doesn't.

Comment: Windows has no snap function except snapping to the 2 halves screen

Answer (score 0):

you can press windows-key plus left/right arrow keys and it will cycle through all windows. Changing from left half of screen to "initial" position to right half of screen. 
For full screen press windows-key and up arrow key.

Comment: So actually, I'm talking about a window snapping itself to the side of the screen when you're moving it. I'm not talking about the window being automatically resized to the height or width of the screen (even tho i realize when it does that it also snaps to the side).